# How do you read a particular cell's content from multiple sheets in an Excel spreadsheet using Java?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, spreadsheet

I have a spreadsheet having more than 100 sheets. I have to read a particular cell content e.g 7th row 5th column from each sheet and write it in a separate sheet in a single column.

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
public static List<String> getCellOfAllSheets (File file, int row, int cell) throws IOException {
    HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(file));
    List<String> rows = new ArrayList<>(workbook.getNumberOfSheets());
    for (int numberOfSheet = 0; numberOfSheet < workbook.getNumberOfSheets(); numberOfSheet++) {
        HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(numberOfSheet);
        rows.add(sheet.getRow(row).getCell(cell).getStringCellValue());
    }
    return rows;
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest using [DataFormatter](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormatter.html#formatCellValue%28org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell%29) to get the cell's value as a string, rather than what you've done, as your code will fail for numeric cells

Comment: @Gagravarr, no one bothers write generics method with switch-case for type of cells. I just wrote an example in right way. May be condition is that type of cells are identical, because its positions also identical.

Comment: Or maybe the code suddenly starts failing at a later date when someone puts a formatted number in! It's best to be defensive, using DataFormatter would mean your code would always work

Comment: Also, [as explained in the docs](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#FileInputStream), if you have a File, use that, [don't go via an InputStream if you have a File](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#FileInputStream)!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're asking is: For a given row and column location (cell) across many sheets, you want to grab the cell there, then save those values into a new Sheet in a single column. Assuming so

First, open the Workbook, and add in a new sheet:

```
Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(new File("input.xlsx"));
Sheet output = wb.createSheet("Found Values");
```

Next, turn the cell reference (eg D3) into the row and cell indexes, using [CellReference](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/util/CellReference.html):

```
 CellReference ref = new CellReference("D3"); // example
 int rowWanted = ref.getRow(); // 2
 int cellWanted = ref.getCol(); // 3
```

Now, we iterate over all of other sheets (except our new one!), grabbing the cell of interest, and writing it into the new sheet

```
 for (int sn=0; sn<wb.getNumberOfSheets()-1; sn++) {
    Sheet input = wb.getSheetAt(sn);
    Row or = output.createRow(sn);
    Cell oc = or.createCell(0);

    Row ir = input.getRow(rowWanted);
    Cell ic = null;
    if (ir != null) {
       ic = ir.getCell(cellWanted, Row.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL);
    }
    if (ic == null) {
       // Empty
       oc.setCellValue("No value in " + input.getSheetName());
    } else {
       // Save the value to the new cell
       switch (ic.getCellType()) {
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                oc.setCellValue(ic.getRichStringCellValue());
                break;
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                oc.setCellValue(ic.getNumericCellValue());
                oc.setCellStyle(ic.getCellStyle()));
                break;
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                oc.setCellValue(ic.getBooleanCellValue());
                break;
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA:
                oc.setCellFormula(ic.getCellFormula());
                break;
            default:
         }
     }
 }
```

Finally, we save the updated file out:

```
 FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("output.xlsx");
 wb.write(out);
 out.close();
```